# Page navigation without page reload Zend framework

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**There is a code:**

```
<div class="pagination">
    <?php 
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pages; $i++) {
            if ($i == $active_page) {
                echo "<span>".$i."</span>";
            } else {
                echo '<a href="?page='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
            }
        }
    ?>
  </div>
```

1-2 page How to make pagination without reloading the page?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `<a>` tags the page will be reloaded (it's a link)

You can trigger `click` event on page numbers and call with ajax (as stated in the tags you put) to fetch some datas to be used to replace the current ones.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) can be something good to read.

Here is a stupid example with hardcoded datas.

```js
function loadDatas(pageNumber)
{
  //Replace me by an ajax call.
  return ("We are now page " + pageNumber);
}

function changePage(pageNumber)
{
  let datas = loadDatas(pageNumber);
  let container = document.getElementById("myContent");
  container.innerHTML = datas;
}
```

```html
<div id="myContent">
  hello world !
</div>

<button onclick="changePage(1)">1</button><button onclick="changePage(2)">2</button><button onclick="changePage(3)">3</button>
```